# Fireflies in my bake texture

Tags: rendering, texturing

Hi I wan't to bake my texture, but I have a lot of fireflies:

[image]

It was baked in 4k and 500 samples. Can you help me?

Comment: In Addition to Ryan's answer, You may also want to check Denoising in the Render Layers Tab, that tends to get rid of fireflies. Also, use bigger light sources, that is the #1 cause of fireflies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing clamp indirect (found next to samples) reduces fireflies.